# Store integers from a text file into variable arrays

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement

I need to plot some coordinate of x, y in MATLAB using some text file.
and I get a problem with reading it using a for loop.

I can figure it in Python but I need help in converting it in MATLAB.

This is some code in Python

```py
   file = open("6.txt", "r")
   x = []
   y = []
   z = []
   for i in file.readlines()[::]:
       if i[0] == "(":
           jam = i.strip('()').split(",")
           x.append(float(jam[0]))
           y.append(float(jam[1]))
           jam = i.strip('()\n').split(",")
           z.append(float(jam[2]))
   '''
```

but in Matlab I initially start with this code

```matlab
    fileID = fopen('1.txt', 'r+');
    formatSpec = '%s';
    for i = fscanf(fileID, '%s')[::]
```

in Python result is

```
x = [1.154545 1.265648 ..... 1.56849] 
Y = [1.0 1.5655 1.61662 ..... 1.0]
```

Comment: Have you tried using the import wizard? With a simple file like this it will be trivial to use the import wizard to generate a script to import this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
content=readmatrix('1.txt') %read the entire content as a matrix
x=content(:1) %extract the first column
y=content(:2) %extract the second column
plot(x,y) %plot the data
```

I cannot test the above code right now, this is why I commented every line that I wrote. But the algorithm remains.

Comment: its a noisy text data so i want to for loop it for preprocessing it

Comment: the file is like
notevook 1
No. of Stroke:28
(0.24049437046051025, 0.22948816418647766, 1.0)
(0.24160410463809967, 0.22948816418647766, 1.0)
..
No. of Stroke: 25
..

Comment: You may as well pre-process the `x` and `y` as much as you wish, between extracting and plotting.